# SQL - Postgresql ERROR

Tags: sql, postgresql, import

I am trying to import datas into postgresql. Windows 7, 64 bit.
My SQL Code is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE films (
  imdib varchar,
  name varchar,
  year integer,
  rating integer,
  votes integer,
  runtime time,
  directors varchar,
  actors varchar,
  genres varchar
);
```

my Copy code is:

```
 COPY films from 'C:\Users\Max\Desktop\imdb_top100.txt' DELIMITER ',';
```

My imdb_top100.txt contains this:

```
tt0111161   The Shawshank Redemption    1994    9.3 1462391 142 mins.   Frank Darabont  Tim Robbins|Morgan Freeman|Bob Gunton   Crime|Drama
```

Getting this Error on Postgresql:

> ERROR:  missing datas for column „name“
>
> CONTEXT:  COPY films, Line 1: „tt0111161  The Shawshank Redemption    1994    9.3 1462391 142 mins.   Frank Darabont  Tim Robbins|Morgan F...“
> ********** Error **********

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is TAB delimited, not comma delimited. So you have to specify tab character as delimiter:

```
COPY films from 'C:\Users\Max\Desktop\imdb_top100.txt' DELIMITER '\t';
```

[Source](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html)

The error reported informs that as there where no comma found, all the line corresponds to the first field, and there is no data left for the following field (name).